# Getting reasonable performance from excel while receiving RTD feeds and avoid blocking

Tags: excel, interop, dde, rtd

I am handling RTD feeds again and remembering the difficulties, but now we have multi-core machines and multi-threading. maybe anyone can advise.
As I understand/rememeber: pushing data into Excel is not one(obvious reasons) so it sends a friendly nod to say your parcel is ready come and get it. Then when Excel has done its nails and feels in the mood, it might get the data.
So this kind of architecture is right back on the dance-floor and hopefully I can make it work.
Problem.
I need to run a bot that examines the data and responds differently;
1. looping or running a winapi timer even is still enough to keep excel busy and no data, or so it seems.
Definitely, executing bot logic , however small, will bring on an Excel fainting fit.

Tried responding via calculation event. Very hit-and-miss and definitely not up to the job. There is no logic obvious as to when and why it fires or does not other than a " bad hair day"
Tried winapi timer looking at the newly acquired data every second comparing to old in a separate data structure, running some EMAs and making a decision. No dice. 
The timer is enough to put a delay up to 10 or even 20 seconds between occasional delivery of data.

Options I am thinking about:
1. The timer running outside of the excel environment and lookin in a the data. e.g an AQddon via pia etc. What I don't know is whether this Addon, perhaps inc C# or vb.net, could utilze multithreading, via tasks I think and do its bit without "scarin the panties of her ladyship"?
2. I remember hearing that XLL UDFs could be asynchronous, does anyone know if this is a potential option?

Any ideas?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This question may be better suited for [**Code Review**](//codereview.stackexchange.com/) This site is for programmers having a specific issue *post their code* and share issues. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code & relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Somelinks: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need code help I need advice from an architectural viewpoint on Excel addins and how they play with RTD feeds. I struggle to see code review being the right option, but I am not an expert on stack Overflow

Comment: @ashleedawg without any code, it's off-topic on Code Review. Furthermore, the question asks about architectural decisions, which are also off-topic on CR. Did you mean [SoftwareEngineering.SE]?

Comment: Apologies, I was not totally au fait with these rules. Perhaps I should have used anther section. Is there another section?

In any case I solved it myself using this article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/what-s-new-in-the-c-api-for-excel